# How can I update or synchronize my existing GitHub repository from IntelliJ idea

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I created a project called Spring-Web-App in IntelliJ Idea and push it to GitHub on the main branch.
now, I have updated a bit of code and locally created a new branch called CreatingViews (from the main branch) in IntelliJ Idea and also added these updated codes to this new Branch (CreatingViews).
I have tried to push it on GitHub by clicking on **Git -> GitHub -> Share Project on GitHub** and afterward received this error: **Project already exists on GitHub**

My problem now is updating this new branch on GitHub from IntelliJ Idea so these changes can be synchronized and reflected.

I have tried to update my existing repository on GitHub from my local project in IntelliJ Idea.
I am expecting the repo on GitHub to be updated or synchronized with the local one that is in IntelliJ Idea instead of creating a new repository on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

A push to remote repository is done via `Git | Push`.

`Share project on a GitHub` does an "initial push" in order to publish a project on a GitHub.
All further commits should be pushed with a `Push` action that can be found either in Git menu or on a toolbar.

Please see here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#push

Comment: I pushed it and received this message "everything is up to date". Thank you very much sir.